# Are questions about my home router and my VoIP Android app on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a [Linksys WRT54GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series#WRT54GL) at home. [VoIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) works as a softphone on my PC, but not with [CSipSimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSipSimple). Is *Super User* OK with that kind of question?

I feel like *[Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour)* is not right place since the question is about the router.

*[Server Fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Fault)* does not accept questions about an home router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super User would be the place for your question about the home router as it falls under the hardware group of subjects the site covers.